# PHP call class method to another class

Tags: php

I've 3 class (Mysqliconn, Users and News).

Mysqliconn.class

```
Class Mysqliconn {
..connect to db
}
```

News.class

```
class News {
private $db;

   public function __construct( Mysqliconn $db ) {

   $this->db = $db; 
   }

   public test() {
     do something... 
   }
 }
```

Users.class

```
class Users {
private $db;

   public function __construct( Mysqliconn $db ) {

   $this->db = $db; 
   }

   public test2() {

     do something...
   }
}
```

In my php page

```
 $db = new Mysqliconn();
 $nw = new News( $db );
 $us = new Users( $db )

 $us->test2();
 $nw->test();
```

My error

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 
passed to Users::__construct() must be an instance of Mysqliconn, 
none given, called in ....\class\class.news.php
```

Now in my class Users I would like to to call a News class method, 
but I get an error if I try to istantiate the class News inside class Users.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: What error? Class doesn't exist? Have you included the class file?

Comment: why don't you inject your `News` class in your `User` constructor?

Comment: `Users` doesn't make sense. How do you have a single `Users`?

Comment: yes it does, if it is a static class

Comment: Why do you pass the $db as a parameter? I would create a singleton class for the Database class.

Comment: @Chris then you deny the possibility to mock the object, and more hidden dependencies. singleton is not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz post what error you are getting. Otherwise it's difficult to capture the problem. But if you dont want to instantiate the news class in the user class you can access it like

```
class News
{
    // news class
}

class Users
{
    public function some_method(News $news){
        // work with the $news object
    }
}

$us = new Users();
$us->some_method(new News(/*$db*/));
```

This is just a basic code to give you an idea of how you can use it. In a production environment you have to take a lot of precautions.

Comment: It's a bad idea. Your code doesn't even work. And it's not a singleton either.

Comment: still not a singleton: remove `function instance()` and calls it dependency injection